# What is the shortest path between several nodes in a particular order without ever using any edge twice?

Tags: math, graph, nodes

Given are a number of ordered nodes in a bidirectional graph with known only positive cost for each edge.

I need to find the shortest path through the given nodes in the particular order that are given while never using any edge twice.

So in contrast to Travelling Salesman problems, I know the order of traversal.

However, the last requirement is key here. Due to not being able to use any edge twice, the locally optimal path between node 1 and 2 could create a suboptimal path between 2 and 3 and so on.

Right now, I am using A-Star in succession to build the total path, but it is clear that this is not optimal.

In pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes - 1; i++)
{
    List<Tile> newPath = importantNodes[i].FindShortestPath(graph, importantNodes[i+1]);
    graph.RemoveEdges(newPath);
    totalPath.Add(newPath);
}
```

So, is there a way to find the global optimum over all given nodes by looking at all of them at the same time to find the optimal path?

Comment: That last requirement probably makes the problem of checking for the existence of such a path NP-complete. Finding the optimal one (if it exists at all) is likely to be NP-hard.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sorry for the unclear description. I tried to make it more precise and added a code snippet!

Comment: It is an interesting problem. If you want a good solution which might not be optimal, an evolutionary algorithm is natural. You could enforce the constraint by heavily penalizing paths which violate it (so that constraint-violating paths rapidly die off)

Comment: @JohnColeman I dont know much about evolutionary algorithms, but this idea seems promising! Can you elaborate a bit more?